# How to use [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse

Tags: .net, powershell

I can't seem to get `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse` to work properly. Each solution I try always returns `Cannot find an overload for "TryParse" and the argument count: "2". (or "3")` despite the fact it shows the following.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                          
-------------------                                                                                                                          
static bool TryParse[TEnum](string value, [ref] TEnum result)                                                                                
static bool TryParse[TEnum](string value, bool ignoreCase, [ref] TEnum result)
```

In my experience any of the following should normally work just fine.

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse('dword',[ref]$Null)
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse('dword',$true,[ref]$Null)
```

In the meantime I can just cast the string as `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]` but I am curious as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve?  These methods are very tricky to work with in PowerShell, in my opinion, and there might be an easier approach.

Comment: @FoxDeploy alot of the scripts I built are used on a wide variety of machines often resulting in me needing to back support all the way to PS 2.0 unfortunately. This function is allowing easier registry manipulation where using normal PScommandlets (set-itemproperty, etc) doesn't always work properly. Some of the influencing issues to using `.net` is the need to verify data types in registry. As I said in the question, I know I can cast the variable to the class, but want to know how to properly use the parse function.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the [RegistryKey.GetValueKind()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluekind) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TryParse` is actually implemented by `System.Enum`, and is a generic method. It returns a `bool` whether the parse succeeded, and the second parameter is an `out` with the actual parse result.

You have a number of issues if you want to use `TryParse`.

Firstly, you cannot call a generic method directly in older versions of Powershell. If you are using PS 7.3 or above then you can now do so:

```
[System.Enum]::TryParse[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]('DWord', [ref]$prm)
```

For versions of Powershell which use .Net Core or .Net 5 (I don't if there are any), you could also use the non-generic version of `TryParse`

```
[System.Enum]::TryParse([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind], 'DWord', [ref]$prm)
```

Be that as it may, in earlier versions you need to use reflection.

```
$arrParams =  @('DWord', $null)

$method = ([System.Enum].GetMethods() | where {($_.Name -eq "TryParse") -and ($_.GetParameters().Length -eq 2) })[0].MakeGenericMethod(@([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]))

$method.Invoke($null, $arrParams);

$arrParams[1]
```

Note that the string parameter is case-sensitive, and therefore must be `'DWord'`

Comment: Thanks. As for "versions of Powershell which use .Net Core or .Net 5": That applies to PowerShell (Core) versions 7.1 and below. 7.2 uses .NET 6, but because it lacks the support for generic method calls, it too must call the non-generic overload.

Answer (score 1):

The `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse()` method by itself will return either `$true` or `$false`, depending if the parsing succeeded or not.

- The first parameter is the **string** value you want parsed converted to one of the [RegistryValueKind enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind) types.
- The last parameter is the variable containing the RegistryValueKind type of choice.
  The method then tries to convert the given string value to that registry kind.
- Optionally, there is an overload with a second parameter in between you can set to `$true` to have it work case-insensitive on the given string value.

example:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse('12345', [ref][Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWord)
```

returns True because '12345' can be converted to integer DWord valuekind.

You can also read back the parsed value like this

```
$result = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWord   # 4
if ([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::TryParse('12345', [ref]$result)) {
    Write-Host "The value can be stored as $result (DWord)"
}
```

Anyway, if your intention is to read registry values and try to determine if the RegistryKind of that entry is correct, I think the [RegistryKey.GetValueKind()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluekind) method would be easier to use

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Charlieface's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71365788/45375):

- It is mentioned in that answer, but let me highlight it: **in PowerShell (Core) 7.3+**<sup>[1]</sup>, **calls to *generic* methods are now fully supported**; unlike in C#, where type arguments are specified enclosed in `<...>`, PowerShell requires the usual `[...]` around type names, as shown below.
- **[`System.Enum.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Enum.TryParse) is case-*sensitive* by default**, but case-*insensitive* lookup is available by opt-in, via the `ignoreCase` parameter.

**Case-*insensitive* calls**:

```bash
# PowerShell (Core)
[enum]::TryParse([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind], 'dword', $true, [ref] $null)

# PowerShell (Core) 7.3+ alternative: invocation as a *generic method*.
# Note:
#  * The type name is part of the method name, before the opening "(" 
#  * 0 rather than $null is passed, because 0 can be converted to
#    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind], which is necessary for matching 
#    the generic method's signature.
[enum]::TryParse[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]('dword', $true, [ref] 0)

# Windows PowerShell: reflection is needed.
# Note: In this case, $null must be passed without [ref].
[enum].GetMethods('Public, Static').
  Where({ $_.IsGenericMethod -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 3 }).
  MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]).
  Invoke($null, ('dword', $true, $null))
```

---

As for **PowerShell-idiomatic solutions**, which are **case-*insensitive* by default** (and invariably, in this case), as PowerShell generally is:

```bash
# Note: 
#  * The assumption is that no strict mode or at most Set-StrictMode -Version 1
#    is in effect.
#  * '...' isn't strictly necessary here; you may also use a *variable*.

[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::'dword' -is [enum] # -> $true
```

It's also worth noting that **working with *string* representations of enumeration values is usually sufficient in PowerShell**, as PowerShell *automatically* converts them to `enum` types.

You can also use a *cast* to the target type:

```bash
# -> [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWord
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind] 'dword'
```

Since such a cast or an implicit conversion *fails*, another alternative to `::TryParse()` is (this one doesn't depend on the active strict mode).

```bash
try { $null = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind] 'dword'; $true } catch { $false }
```

---

<sup>[1] 7.3 is yet to be released as of this writing, but already available in *preview* versions - see [the repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)</sup>